# Android-rdp-client setup and compiling

Tags: android, remote-access, remote-desktop, rdp

I have tried to compile the android-rdp-client(downloaded source code from [here](http://android-rdp-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/androidRDPClient/) ), but could not get an output except a blank screen. I have set the username, IP, password etc to access my PC via my android phone. The code is below.

**-- CODE --**

```
import gnu.getopt.Getopt;
import gnu.getopt.LongOpt;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import net.propero.rdp.Common;
import net.propero.rdp.ConnectionException;
import net.propero.rdp.Constants;
import net.propero.rdp.Options;
import net.propero.rdp.RDPClientChooser;
import net.propero.rdp.RdesktopException;
import net.propero.rdp.Rdp;
import net.propero.rdp.rdp5.Rdp5;
import net.propero.rdp.rdp5.VChannels;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class RdpActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidRDPClientActivity";

    static boolean keep_running;

    static boolean loggedon;

    static boolean readytosend;

    static boolean showTools;

    static String mapFile = "en-gb";

    static String keyMapLocation = "";

    static String server = "localhost";
    static String password="4104636";
    int logonflags = Rdp.RDP_LOGON_NORMAL;

    // static SendEvent toolFrame = null;

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//      Intent intent = new Intent();
//      intent.setClass(AndroidRDPClientActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
//      startActivity(intent);
         Rdesktop();

    }

    private void Rdesktop() {
                init();

    }

    private void init() {
        keep_running = true;
        loggedon = false; // æœªç™»é™†
        readytosend = false;
        showTools = false;
        mapFile = "en-gb";
        keyMapLocation = "";
        // toolFrame = null;

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        RDPClientChooser Chooser = new RDPClientChooser();
        String[] args = { "127.0.0.1" };
        if (Chooser.RunNativeRDPClient(args)) { // Chooser.RunNativeRDPClient(args)
            // = false
            if (!Common.underApplet)
                System.exit(0);
        }
        int logonflags = Rdp.RDP_LOGON_NORMAL;
        // æ­£å¸¸ç™»é™† è‡ªåŠ¨ç™»é™†

        boolean fKdeHack = false;
        int c;
        String arg;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        LongOpt[] alo = new LongOpt[15];
        alo[0] = new LongOpt("debug_key", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[1] = new LongOpt("debug_hex", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[2] = new LongOpt("no_paste_hack", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[3] = new LongOpt("log4j_config", LongOpt.REQUIRED_ARGUMENT, sb, 0);
        alo[4] = new LongOpt("packet_tools", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[5] = new LongOpt("quiet_alt", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, sb, 0);
        alo[6] = new LongOpt("no_remap_hash", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[7] = new LongOpt("no_encryption", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[8] = new LongOpt("use_rdp4", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[9] = new LongOpt("use_ssl", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[10] = new LongOpt("enable_menu", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[11] = new LongOpt("console", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[12] = new LongOpt("load_licence", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[13] = new LongOpt("save_licence", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null, 0);
        alo[14] = new LongOpt("persistent_caching", LongOpt.NO_ARGUMENT, null,
                0);

        String progname = "properJavaRDP";// ç¨‹åº?å??

        Getopt g = new Getopt("properJavaRDP", args,
                "bc:d:f::g:k:l:m:n:p:s:t:T:u:o:r:", alo);

        // ClipChannel clipChannel = new ClipChannel(); //çœ?ç•¥

        while ((c = g.getopt()) != -1) {
            switch (c) {

            case 0:
                switch (g.getLongind()) {
                case 0:
                    Options.debug_keyboard = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Options.debug_hexdump = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    arg = g.getOptarg();
                    PropertyConfigurator.configure(arg);
                    // logger.info("Log4j using config file " + arg);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    showTools = true;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Options.altkey_quiet = true;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Options.remap_hash = false;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Options.packet_encryption = false;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Options.use_rdp5 = false;
                    // Options.server_bpp = 8;
                    Options.set_bpp(8);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Options.use_ssl = true;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    Options.enable_menu = true;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    Options.console_session = true;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    Options.load_licence = true;
                    break;
                case 13:
                    Options.save_licence = true;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    Options.persistent_bitmap_caching = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    // usage();
                }
                break;

            case 'o':
                Options.set_bpp(Integer.parseInt(g.getOptarg()));
                break;
            case 'b':
                Options.low_latency = false;
                break;
            case 'm':
                mapFile = g.getOptarg();
                break;
            case 'c':
                Options.directory = g.getOptarg();
                break;
            case 'd':
                Options.domain = g.getOptarg();
                break;
            case 'f':
                // Dimension screen_size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                // .getScreenSize();

                // Options.width = screen_size.width & ~3;
                // Options.height = screen_size.height;

                Options.width = 600 & ~3;
                Options.height = 800;
                Options.fullscreen = true;
                arg = g.getOptarg();
                if (arg != null) {
                    if (arg.charAt(0) == 'l')
                        fKdeHack = true;
                    else {
                        System.err.println(progname
                                + ": Invalid fullscreen option '" + arg + "'");
                        // usage();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 'g':
                arg = g.getOptarg();
                int cut = arg.indexOf("x", 0);
                if (cut == -1) {
                    System.err.println(progname + ": Invalid geometry: " + arg);
                    // usage();
                }
                Options.width = Integer.parseInt(arg.substring(0, cut)) & ~3;
                Options.height = Integer.parseInt(arg.substring(cut + 1));
                break;
            case 'k':
                arg = g.getOptarg();
                // Options.keylayout = KeyLayout.strToCode(arg);
                if (Options.keylayout == -1) {
                    System.err.println(progname + ": Invalid key layout: "
                            + arg);
                    // usage();
                }
                break;
            case 'l':
                arg = g.getOptarg();
                switch (arg.charAt(0)) {
                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                    // logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
                    break;
                case 'i':
                case 'I':
                    // logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
                    break;
                case 'w':
                case 'W':
                    // logger.setLevel(Level.WARN);
                    break;
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                    // logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
                    break;
                case 'f':
                case 'F':
                    // logger.setLevel(Level.FATAL);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.err.println(progname + ": Invalid debug level: "
                            + arg.charAt(0));
                    // usage();
                }
                break;
            case 'n':
                Options.hostname = g.getOptarg();
                break;
            case 'p':
                Options.password = g.getOptarg();
                logonflags |= Rdp.RDP_LOGON_AUTO;
                break;
            case 's':
                Options.command = g.getOptarg();
                break;
            case 'u':
                Options.username = g.getOptarg();
                break;
            case 't':
                arg = g.getOptarg();
                try {
                    Options.port = Integer.parseInt(arg);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nex) {
                    System.err.println(progname + ": Invalid port number: "
                            + arg);
                    // usage();
                }
                break;
            case 'T':
                Options.windowTitle = g.getOptarg().replace('_', ' ');
                break;
            case 'r':
                Options.licence_path = g.getOptarg();
                break;

            case '?':
            default:
                // usage();
                break;

            }
        }

        if (fKdeHack) {
            Options.height -= 46;
        }

        String server = null;
        logonflags |= Rdp.RDP_LOGON_AUTO;   // è‡ªåŠ¨ç™»é™†çš„è¯?ï¼Œ éœ€è¦?å¡«ä¸Šç”¨æˆ·å??å’Œå¯†ç ?
        if (g.getOptind() < args.length) {
            int colonat = args[args.length - 1].indexOf(":", 0);
            if (colonat == -1) {
                server = args[args.length - 1];
            } else {
                server = args[args.length - 1].substring(0, colonat);
                Options.port = Integer.parseInt(args[args.length - 1]
                        .substring(colonat + 1));
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println(progname + ": A server name is required!");
            // usage();
        }

        VChannels channels = new VChannels();
        // Initialise all RDP5 channels
        if (Options.use_rdp5) {
            // TODO: implement all relevant channels
            // if (Options.map_clipboard)

            // channels.register(clipChannel);
        }
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String osvers = System.getProperty("os.version");
        if (os.equals("Windows 2000") || os.equals("Windows XP"))
            Options.built_in_licence = true;

        Log.i(TAG, "Operating System is " + os + " version " + osvers);

        if (os.startsWith("Linux"))
            Constants.OS = Constants.LINUX;
        else if (os.startsWith("Windows"))
            Constants.OS = Constants.WINDOWS;
        else if (os.startsWith("Mac"))
            Constants.OS = Constants.MAC;

        if (Constants.OS == Constants.MAC)
            Options.caps_sends_up_and_down = false;

        Rdp5 RdpLayer = null;
        Common.rdp = RdpLayer;
        // RdesktopFrame window = new RdesktopFrame_Localised();

        boolean[] deactivated = new boolean[1];
        int[] ext_disc_reason = new int[1];

        while (keep_running) {
            // logger.debug("Initialising RDP layer...");
            RdpLayer = new Rdp5(channels);
            Common.rdp = RdpLayer;
            // logger.debug("Registering drawing surface...");
            // RdpLayer.registerDrawingSurface(window);
            // logger.debug("Registering comms layer...");
            // window.registerCommLayer(RdpLayer);
            loggedon = false;
            readytosend = false;

            if (server.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost"))
                server = "127.0.0.1";

            // Attempt to connect to server on port Options.port
            try {
                RdpLayer.connect(Options.username, InetAddress
                        .getByName(server), logonflags, Options.domain,
                        password, Options.command, Options.directory);

                // Remove to get rid of sendEvent tool
                if (showTools) {
                    // toolFrame = new SendEvent(RdpLayer);
                    // toolFrame.show();
                }
                // End

                if (keep_running) {

                    /*
                     * By setting encryption to False here, we have an
                     * encrypted login packet but unencrypted transfer of
                     * other packets
                     */
                    if (!Options.packet_encryption)
                        Options.encryption = false;

                    // logger.info("Connection successful");
                    // now show window after licence negotiation
                    RdpLayer.mainLoop(deactivated, ext_disc_reason);
                    if (deactivated[0]) {
                        /* clean disconnect */
                        System.exit(-1);

                        // return 0;
                    } else {
                        System.exit(-1);

                    }

                    keep_running = false; // exited main loop
                    if (!readytosend) {
                        // maybe the licence server was having a comms
                        // problem, retry?
                        String msg1 = "The terminal server disconnected before licence negotiation completed.";
                        String msg2 = "Possible cause: terminal server could not issue a licence.";
                        String[] msg = { msg1, msg2 };
                        // logger.warn(msg1);
                        // logger.warn(msg2);
                        // window.showErrorDialog(msg);
                    }
                } // closing bracket to if(running)

                // Remove to get rid of tool window
                // if (showTools)
                // toolFrame.dispose();
                // End

            } catch (ConnectionException e) {
                String msg[] = { "Connection Exception", e.getMessage() };
                // window.showErrorDialog(msg);
                //System.exit(-1);
                this.finish();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // error(e, RdpLayer, window, true);
            } catch (SocketException s) {
                if (RdpLayer.isConnected()) {
                    // logger.fatal(s.getClass().getName() + " "
                    // + s.getMessage());
                    // // s.printStackTrace();
                    // error(s, RdpLayer, window, true);
                    // Rdesktop.exit(0, RdpLayer, window, true);
                }
            } catch (RdesktopException e) {
                String msg1 = e.getClass().getName();
                String msg2 = e.getMessage();
                // logger.fatal(msg1 + ": " + msg2);

                e.printStackTrace(System.err);

                if (!readytosend) {
                    // maybe the licence server was having a comms
                    // problem, retry?
                    String msg[] = {
                            "The terminal server reset connection before licence negotiation completed.",
                            "Possible cause: terminal server could not connect to licence server.",
                            "Retry?" };
                    // boolean retry = window.showYesNoErrorDialog(msg);
                    // if (!retry) {
                    // logger.info("Selected not to retry.");
                    // Rdesktop.exit(0, RdpLayer, window, true);
                    // } else {
                    // if (RdpLayer != null && RdpLayer.isConnected()) {
                    // logger.info("Disconnecting ...");
                    // RdpLayer.disconnect();
                    // logger.info("Disconnected");
                    // }
                    // logger.info("Retrying connection...");
                    // keep_running = true; // retry
                    // continue;
                    // }
                } else {
                    String msg[] = { e.getMessage() };
                    // window.showErrorDialog(msg);
                    // Rdesktop.exit(0, RdpLayer, window, true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // logger.warn(e.getClass().getName() + " " +
                // e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                // error(e, RdpLayer, window, true);
            }
        }
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

What should I do to get this code working? Is there any other requirements like a server side software for my windows machine? For now I have enabled remote desktop connections to my PC.